# How can we call a setter method on an mocked instance of an interface in junit?(this is because we can't access its implementation class)

Tags: junit, mockito

```
public A getA()
{
   A a = Mockito.mock(A.class);
   Mockito.when(a.setId(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn("12");  
   return a; 
}
```

cannot call since void returning method
cannot call real method because the mocked object is of interface instance

Comment: Is `setId` void ("void returning method"), or does it return a String (as in your code example)? Where/when are you trying to call a real method? And, most importantly, why are you trying to mock a setter when it's much more appropriate to _verify_ that your system-under-test calls a setter or _stub_ the _getter_ so your system-under-test sees the right value?

Comment: What is the purpose here ? Can't you stub getter method or inject mocks ?